# How to increase max header size for Istio 1.6.8?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

Situation:

Service A and B. Request headers from A to B can be up to 81KiB. As of that currently it errors out with 431 response.

Services are in default namespace.
Istio is on istio-system namespace.
istio-config namespace was not created during installation.

Istio 1.6.8. Both services has sidecart istio-proxy.

Following envoyfilter used:

```
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: max-request-headers
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER # http connection manager is a filter in Envoy
    match:
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager"
          max_request_headers_kb: 96
```

But it does not work.

There were attempts to create this filter in `default`, `istio-system` and `istio-config` namespaces. Does not help.

Analysis of routes for those services by `istioctl proxy-config routes service-a --port 8080 -o json` does not show that filter was applied.

So from all of this there are several questions:

1. How properly adjust max_header_size_kb for envoy?
2. What is proper flow for debugging such situations especially was envoy config applied?
3. Does Istio applies EnvoyFilter on the fly or do i need to restart istio services?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with provided EnvoyFilter in example is version mismatch. Example is for Istio 1.7.x while in environment istio is at 1.6.8 version.

Issue was solved by changing manifest to this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: max-request-headers
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER # http connection manager is a filter in Envoy
    match:
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager" # istio 1.6.8
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager" # istio 1.6.8
          max_request_headers_kb: 96
```